# Why does docker allow me to bind to host port 81 but not 4040?

Tags: ubuntu, docker

Let me preface this question with; I have found a way to make this work, I am just wondering why I had to do it this way. So I have Installed docker on my Droplet, and pulled the ghost image down. I can successfully create a container and run it. It says that it's running and everything is fine. Now here's the weird behavior. When I bind it to host port 4040, I cannot access the server. The port is correctly bound (because when I try to run a second instance, I am getting the error that it is already bound), I just can't access the application. When I try running nmap it does not show that the port is open. However, when I run the container bound to port 81, I have no problems at all. I am really curious as to why this is happening. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

It's got nothing to do with Docker. The problem is likely one of

1. You have a firewall or AWS security group or something similar blocking you from 4040. You can verify this by running `nc -l 4040` on your server and trying to connect.
2. You are running on Mac OS, Windows, or otherwise have your Docker server on a different machine than you imagine. Your local machine is listening on port 81 and that's what you're connecting to (not the containerized service you think you're connecting to).